# Storing items in a module-level list

Tags: python, list

How can I save the items in lists because when using `Sign_in` function, it prints "invalid" not "success"?

```
import lists_module

def Sign_in():
    email = input("Enter Your Email").strip()
    password = input("Enter your password").strip()
    if email in lists_module.emails and int(password) in lists_module.passwords:
        print("success")
    else : print("invalid")

def Sign_up():
    first_name = input("Enter Your First Name").strip().capitalize()
    last_name = input("Enter Your Last Name").strip().capitalize()
    new_email = input("Enter Your Email").strip().capitalize()
    new_password = input("Enetr New Password").strip().capitalize()
    lists_module.Fname.append(first_name)
    lists_module.Lname.append(last_name)
    lists_module.emails.append(new_email)
    lists_module.passwords.append(new_password)
    print("Sign-In Page")
    Sign_in()
```

Note: `Fname` and `Lname` and `email` are empty lists in another module.

Comment: Did you mean to `.capitalize()` the email in the `Sign_up` function? And the password too?

Comment: when I entered data in Sign_up function it must be stored at specified lists but when i call Sign_in function to check if the entered data exist in lists it output invalid because the data not stored actually when I call the Sign_up function

Comment: so any valid email can sign in with any valid number? sounds insecure.

Comment: I mean, you don't `.capitalize()` neither the email nor the password in `Sign_in`, but `Sign_up` capitalised them first and then saved the capitalised versions. So if you input `"email@example.com"`, it would be saved as `"Email@example.com"`, but `email in lists_module.emails` will check whether the NON-capitalized email is in the list, which will fail since _all_ emails _are_ capitalized

Comment: No module named lists_module, and this defines functions but does not call them. Also provide the input and expected output.

Comment: You store the password as a string, but convert it to an integer when comparing, so that will never work.  And as already pointed out any email can sign in with any password even if that is corrected.  What you probably want is a dictionary containing email keys and fname,lname,password as a value, then check if email in dictionary and compare against the password.

Answer (score 1):

The appended values are just temporary. Use file I/O for permanent changes. I.e.:

```
def Sign_in():
    email = input("Enter Your Email").strip()
    password = input("Enter your password").strip()
    emails = open('emails.txt','r').readlines()
    passwords = open('passwords.txt','r').readlines()
    if email in emails and password in passwords:
        print("success")
    else : print("invalid")


def Sign_up():
    first_name = input("Enter Your First Name").strip().capitalize()
    last_name = input("Enter Your Last Name").strip().capitalize()
    new_email = input("Enter Your Email").strip()
    new_password = input("Enetr New Password").strip()
    open('fnames.txt','a+').write(first_name+'\n')
    open('lnames.txt','a+').write(first_name+'\n')
    open('emails.txt','a+').write(new_email+'\n')
    open('passwords.txt','a+').write(new_password+'\n')
    print("Sign-In Page")
    Sign_in()
```

This will write the values to files on your computer, then read them from those files, that way, when you run the prorgam a second time, the changes are permanent.

Comment: 1) is better to open files with the `with` statement, 2)I think you want the `"a"` mode, with the `"w+"` mode it just overwrite the file with the most recent one which make it saving to a file kind of pointless, don't you think?, and for storing several of those in a file you need some sort of separator in order to differentiate each one later on

Answer (score 0):

The reason you keep getting "invalid" is because you don't process the user's input consistently in the `Sign_up()` and `Sign_in()` functions. One way to update the lists in the `lists_module` is by using the [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) module to register a function that will be executed when the script ends.

```
import atexit
import lists_module


def Sign_in():
    email = input("Enter Your Email ").strip().capitalize()
    password = input("Enter your password ").strip().capitalize()

    if email in lists_module.emails and password in lists_module.passwords:
        print("success")
    else:
        print("invalid")

def Sign_up():
    first_name = input("Enter Your First Name ").strip().capitalize()
    last_name = input("Enter Your Last Name ").strip().capitalize()
    new_email = input("Enter Your Email ").strip().capitalize()
    new_password = input("Enetr New Password ").strip().capitalize()
    lists_module.Fname.append(first_name)
    lists_module.Lname.append(last_name)
    lists_module.emails.append(new_email)
    lists_module.passwords.append(new_password)

    print("Sign-In Page")
    Sign_in()

def update_lists_module():
    with open('lists_module.py', 'w') as outp:
        for name in dir(lists_module):
            if not name.startswith('_'):
                value = getattr(lists_module, name)
                outp.write(f'{name} = {value!r}\n')


atexit.register(update_lists_module)
Sign_up()
```